# R function to get directory name of a file as characters

Tags: r, directory, path

I can create a list of csv files in folder_A:

```
list1 <- dir_ls("path to folder_A")
```

I can define a function to add a column with filenames and combine these files into one dataframe:

```
read_and_save_combo <- function(fileX){
  read_csv(fileX) %>% 
    mutate(fileX = path_file(fileX)}

combo_df <- map_df(list1, read_and_save_combo)
```

I want to add another column with enclosing folder name (would be the same for all files, folder_A).  If I use dirname() on an individual file, I get the full parent directory path to folder_A.  I only want the characters "folder_A".  If I use dirname() as part of the function, I get another column but its filled with "."  Less importantly, I don't know why I get the "." instead of the full path, but more importantly is there a function like path_parentfoldername, that would let me add a new column with only the name of the folder containing each file to each row of the combined dataframe?

Thanks!

Edit:
New function for clarity after answers:

```
read_and_save_combo <- function(fileX){
  read_csv(fileX) %>% 
    mutate(filename = path_file(fileX), foldername = dirname(fileX) %>%
             str_replace(pattern = ".*/", replacement = ""))}
```

This works because . is the wildcard but * modifies the meaning to 0-infinity characters, so ".*" is any character and any number of characters preceding /.  Gregor said this but now I understand it.

Also, I was getting the column filled with ".", because in the function, I was reading *one* file, but then trying to mutate with dirname operating on the list, which is a vector with multiple elements (more than one file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dirname` + `basename` :

```
list1 <- list.files('folder_A_path', full.names = TRUE)

read_and_save_combo <- function(fileX) {
  readr::read_csv(fileX) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(fileX = basename(dirname(fileX)))
}

combo_df <- purrr::map_df(list1, read_and_save_combo)
```

If your file is at the path `'Users/Downloads/FolderA/Filename.csv'` :

```
dirname('Users/Downloads/FolderA/Filename.csv')
#[1] "Users/Downloads/FolderA"

basename(dirname('Users/Downloads/FolderA/Filename.csv'))
#[1] "FolderA"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak!  This solution is easier to write, thanks.  I read the Help for these functions but your examples are much better.  Is string processing all that underlies "path_file" and "basename" or is there more to it?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Those functions depend on string processing.

Answer (score 0):

`"path to folder_A"` is a bad example, use `"path/to/folder_A"`. You need to delete everything from the start through the last `/`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("path/to/folder_A", pattern = ".*/", replacement = "")
# [1] "folder_A"
```

If you're worried about `\\` or other non-standard things, use `dirname()` as the input.

Comment: Thanks Gregor!  I used dirname() as you suggested, which will simplify filepaths for me in the future as I am on Windows (copying filepath and adding \'s is a pain).  I edited my post with the new function, which works!

Comment: @kayak you should put your working function as an answer, not in your question! Answering your own question is encouraged (though there's a 24 hour wait period before you can accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do what I wanted, using the helpful answers above:

```
read_and_save_combo <- function(file){
  read_csv(file) %>% 
    mutate(filename = path_file(file), foldername = basename(dirname(file)))}
```

```
read_and_save_combo <- function(file){
  read_csv(file) %>% 
    mutate(filename = path_file(file), foldername = dirname(file) %>%
             str_replace(pattern = ".*/", replacement = ""))}
```

Other basic things I learned that could be helpful for other beginners:
(1) While writing the function, point all the functions (read_csv(), dirname(), etc.) at a uniform variable (here written as "file" but it could be just a letter "g" or whatever you choose).  Then you will avoid the problem I had where part of the function is acting on one file and another part is acting on a list.
(2)

```
filex and fileX
```

appear far too similar to each other using certain fonts, which can mess you up (capitalization).